# Monitor registry changes for sub-program/operation

Tags: windows-registry, monitoring

I have a problem with a program, or rather said with a bought component of this program because it constantly "stops working".

So i got the task to find out what that subprogram changes in the registry, so that we might replicate it ourselves and for our needs.

The problem is now how do i do that?

I already found RegShot with which i can make RegSnapshot before and after installation and compare. I tried it with a couple more configurations but as it includes ALL registry changes, and not just from the subprogram, the compare txt is HUGE! And i have no clue what changes are traced back to what program-part.

Is there a program (like RegShot or ProcMon) that can help me sort out subprograms or supoperations to only monitor these registry changes?

Comment: Just apply the filter to ProcMon?

Comment: You can do that in Process monitor. Just apply a filter with process name and use that program name.

Comment: @Biswa I did so but everything seems to run under msiexec, but it at least limted the results because i could choose the program window

Comment: @Biswa The list ONLY finds msiexec.exe because (the setup, the program i want to monitor) is build on that. If i were to filter it out i would get no results at all sadly.

Comment: Then monitor the registry changes of msiexec and or extract msi files with [lessmsi](http://lessmsi.activescott.com/).

Comment: @lessmsi Yes i just walk through the whole msiexec's 100 or so changes. Its managable :)